# Make a div slide in on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a website where I have a div for my header, menu, and content the content div is within its own wrapper div. I would like to animate my divs by making the header and menu appear by fading in, and after the fade animations are complete, have the content slide in from the left. Ideally I would want to use jquery to make the animations. How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: a simple googling will give you your answer :)

Comment: This Question is `too broad`

Comment: It's very simple. We cannot write it for you. Just try to find out.

Comment: @jewelnguyen8 What if he pays 10$ for Answer?

Comment: Well @jQueryAngryBird it depends if he really want to hire you.

Comment: It's so simple. Hire me 2$ an hours. I will do all the things for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will help you,

```
$('#hidden_div_id').slideDown('slow');
```

`display:block` should be done along with it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr4sn52m/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#headerID, #menuID").fadeIn("slow", function(){ 
    $("#contentID").slideDown('slow');
});
```